# filtering pollable channel

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a pollable channel and a filter right downstream of it. Is it possible to poll such channel with a filter or should I use some intermediate conponent in between(I checked service-activator. It can at least accept the pollable channel, but maybe there are better options for that, like some gateway):

```
    <task:executor id="task-executor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="100"/>

    <int:channel id="inputChannel">
        <int:queue capacity="100" />
    </int:channel>

    <!--The filter is never triggered. The flow goes from input-channel preSend fight to its postSend-->
    <int:filter id="mailFilter" input-channel="inputChannel"
                output-channel="outputChannel" expression="@mailFilter.acceptMail(payload)"
                auto-startup="true" discard-channel="error-handler">
        <int:poller task-executor='task-executor' fixed-delay='500'>
        </int:poller>
</int:filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the post send is immediately after the pre send - it is very fast to dump the message into the queue.

The filter is invoked on the task executor thread not the sending thread.

You will see a `preReceive` log (at TRACE level) and `postReceive` at DEBUG level.

**EDIT:**

I just ran a test with no problems...

```
<int:channel id="foo">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:filter input-channel="foo" output-channel="toRabbit" expression="true">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="2000" />
</int:filter>


10:29:53.792 TRACE [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] preReceive on channel 'foo'
10:29:53.795 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4][org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter] Poll resulted in Message: [Payload String content=xxx][Headers={id=9b5bf399-a137-daec-58bd-7cf7216d3dfc, timestamp=1429090193794}]
10:29:53.795 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4][org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] preSend on channel 'foo', message: [Payload String content=xxx][Headers={id=9b5bf399-a137-daec-58bd-7cf7216d3dfc, timestamp=1429090193794}]
10:29:53.795 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4][org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] postSend (sent=true) on channel 'foo', message: [Payload String content=xxx][Headers={id=9b5bf399-a137-daec-58bd-7cf7216d3dfc, timestamp=1429090193794}]
10:29:53.795 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] postReceive on channel 'foo', message: [Payload String content=xxx][Headers={id=9b5bf399-a137-daec-58bd-7cf7216d3dfc, timestamp=1429090193794}]
10:29:53.795 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer] Poll resulted in Message: [Payload String content=xxx][Headers={id=9b5bf399-a137-daec-58bd-7cf7216d3dfc, timestamp=1429090193794}]
10:29:53.796 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter] org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter@2ecd0256 received message: [Payload String content=xxx][Headers={id=9b5bf399-a137-daec-58bd-7cf7216d3dfc, timestamp=1429090193794}]
```

Comment: Ok, I see your point but the filter is not triggered at all. When I add a service-activator instead, it triggers almost immediately after the message is received.

Comment: There must be something else going on; a `filter` is no different from any consuming endpoint. I just ran a test with no problems. Will edit the answer with my results.